# Visual studio 'Break all' option does not work anymore

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I sometimes used the 'Break all' (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd>) option to catch any events, in order to understand a flow of code that I did not familiar with.
For some reason it stopped working and does not break at all.

I use VS 2010 as an IDE.

Comment: Does `Debug -> Break All` work?

Comment: No.That exactly the problem.If I use VS2015 as an IDE, it works, so i believe it's a configuration issue in VS2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out  that checking 'Enable Just My Code', in debug menu options, solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue today in Visual Studio 2019.

In my case, the problem is that I was trying to "Break All" in an empty Visual Studio instance (i.e. I had not yet loaded a project/solution). I was debugging a process that spans across many projects, so I was hoping to break on the process, and then browse to find applicable source code based on the callstack.

I fixed the problem by loading a relevant project in Visual Studio before clicking "Break All."

Answer (score 0):

Symbols are a fundamental requirement for debugging.
must add Symbos.
[image]